# Why is my JToggleButton not accepting my setDisabledIcon()?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtogglebutton

I'm trying to skin a `JToggleButton` with 2 icons for the default and the toggle state. Why would it not change its display anyways, although I set an icon for both states?

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

public class RepeatButton extends JToggleButton {


    private ImageIcon repeatIcon;
    private ImageIcon repeatIconUnchecked;


    public RepeatButton() {
        repeatIcon = new ImageIcon("media_repeat.png");
        repeatIcon.setImage(repeatIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(repeatIcon.getIconWidth()/2, repeatIcon.getIconHeight()/2,Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING));
        repeatIconUnchecked = new ImageIcon("media_repeat_uncheckedalt.png");
        repeatIconUnchecked.setImage(repeatIconUnchecked.getImage().getScaledInstance(repeatIconUnchecked.getIconWidth()/2, repeatIconUnchecked.getIconHeight()/2,Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING));
        this.setIcon(repeatIcon);
        this.setDisabledIcon(repeatIconUnchecked);
        this.setBorder(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the time of deployment, those icons will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, they must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form the `URL` for the `ImageIcon`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *disabled icon* is the icon that will be used when your JToggleButton gets *disabled* by doing:

```
btn.setEnabled(false);
```

And has nothing to do with the *isSelected* state.

You can do it manually by changing the icon by using a listener for the selected state. Or you could use the `setSelectedIcon()` method for that.

Comment: @nakih: don't mistake inexperience for stupidity. You will get better at this with continued effort, but most important -- please *do* check out the API as this answer is readily obtained from this useful tool.

Comment: I did check. The fact I was disabling something by toggling the button was stuck in head. I misstook isSelected() as isDisabled().